# Prove existence and uniqueness of the solution to the following DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Given the following differential equation:

$$\displaystyle
\begin{split}
\dot x_1 = -x_1^3  \qquad\qquad \quad\,\,\, &x_1(0)=x_{10} \\
\dot x_2 = x_1-x_2-x_1^3\qquad &x_2(0) = x_{20}
\end{split}
$$

How can one prove or disprove that it has a unique solution for $t\in [0,\infty)$? My current approach is to solve the first equation to obtain:

$$\displaystyle
x_1 = \text{sgn}(x_{10})\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\displaystyle x_{10}^2}+2t}}
$$

and then combine both equations to obtain:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x_2-x_1) = -(x_2-x_1)\Rightarrow x_2-x_1=(x_{20}-x_{10})e^{-t}
$$
Therefore the solution for $x_2$ is
$$
x_2=\text{sgn}(x_{10})\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\displaystyle x_{10}^2}+2t}}+(x_{20}-x_{10})e^{-t}
$$

However, while the solution to the second DE is unique (it's linear), I'm not sure if the solution to $\dot x_1=-x_1^3$ is unique.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: There is a theorem of Cauchy regarding existence and uniqueness. If you may use this then it guarantees uniqueness of your solution since  your vector fields are smooth  (you should btw separate the case $x_{10}=0$). If you can't use Cauchy it becomes more tricky and depends on what tools you have.

Comment: Could you point me to this theorem please?

Comment: Not very palpable but you may look in: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem (or wikipedia).    Otherwise if you want I may sketch a bit more of what it says?

Comment: Sure, please do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ode of the form: $(\dot{x}_1,\dot{x}_2)=(f_1(x_1,x_2), f_2(x_1,x_2))$, $t\geq 0$  with initial condition $(x_1(0),x_2(0))=(x_{10},x_{20})$ is also known as a Cauchy problem. The famous Cauchy-Lipshitz  theorem states that when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuously differentiable (more generally: locally Lipschitz) then the problem has a unique socalled 'maximal' solution. This means there is a unique time $0<T\leq +\infty$ and a solution $(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ which exists for $0\leq t <T$ but can not be extended beyond $T$.

In your case $f_1(x_1,x_2)=-x_1^3$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2)=x_1-x_2-x_1^3$ are continuously differentiable (e.g. because the Jacobian depends continuously on $(x_1$, $x_2$) so we have existence and uniqueness of a maximal solution. Usually a problem is to show that $T=+\infty$ (so that the solution exists for all times) and often one needs to pay a lot of attention to this. But in your case this is fine because you have already found a solution.

I omit a discussion of the 'domain' on which you consider the ode. In any case yours is well defined for all values of $(x_1,x_2)$ in the plane.

Comment: So the basic idea is that from my problem, without solving it I can tell that a unique solution up to $T$ exists. Since I found a solution, it must be the unique one up to $T$ and, as it happens, my solution actually exists up until $T=+\infty$. Therefore, a unique solution exists for $t\in [0,\infty)$?

Comment: Exactly! Note that if you try to go backwards in time (which is also a well-defined Cauchy-problem) then your solution will 'blow up' in finite time because there is $T<0$ for which the denominator inside the square root becomes zero. The maximal solution only exists after that (negative) time. Hope this does not confuse you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the solution is bounded interval the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) applies. The problem is that $x\mapsto x^3$ is only locally Lipshitz, not not uniformly. So you get the existence of a (unique) solution on some (maximal) open interval, $[0, T)$, say. To get a global solution you need to show that the solution remains bounded as $t\rightarrow T$ and that the solution admits a continuous extension of the solution on $[0,T]$. That way (if that works out) you could show that $T=\infty$

If you explicit solution is globally and bounded on bounded intervals the theorem implies it's uniqueness (since on bounded sets $x^3$ is uniformly Lipshitz).